# Hooking in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, clr, hook

I want to hook some function in .Net is there a way to do it?
I don’t mean windows hooking, I want to hook CLR function like when DataAdapter.Fill is called
Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean by `hook`? `DataAdepter.Fill` is an overloaded method of the `DataAdepter` class. You need to explain what you are trying to achieve. As you can see from the answers already posted, different people understand it differently.

Comment: **Why?** What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible in general.
For diagnostics purposes, you can use [Moles](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/moles/), but I wouldn't recommend it for production use,

In specific cases, you can make an inherited class that overrides a virtual function.

Comment: Hey SLaks, congrats for the 100K+ reputation score! And thanks for your contributions to the SO community! =)

Answer (score 1):

The profiling API has what you want.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301725.aspx

But I've never used it, so good luck!

Comment: well, maybe not, but if you want to monitor that, then probably best off raising events. But the question didn't say which functions they wanted to hook into...

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it's possible with .Net framework itself, but what you are looking for is called Aspect Oriented Programming. .Net versions works by modifying the IL code that Visual Studio generates during compilation.

Look here for more information: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/UsingAOPInCSharp.aspx